# Control Flow Between Server and Client and Back to Server for Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a question about the control flow between some JavaScript code running as bound functions within a google spreadsheet - so server side - and a dialog (that happens to be Modal, but Modeless is the same) that is client side.

While the code examples below work fine in that the dialog successfully calls the server side function as per the line below, and the *withSuccessHandler* works too.

> `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success_callback).getCredentials(this.parentNode)`

But what I actually want to achieve is for some server side code to carry on executing once the dialog has gone; ideally from the point the .showModalDialog() function was called, but I'd be happy just passing control back to any server-side function.

Some example software is below; don't forget this works, just not how I want it too! Essentially the event handler for a menu item created by the the OnOpen() function calls a modal dialog to prompt the user for security credentials.

```
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('authorization_dialog');
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
          .showModalDialog(html, 'Authorization Dialog');
```

The HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>    
        Authorization Code:&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="authorization_code"><br><br>
        Account ID:&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="account_id"><br><br>
        Enter account details...
        <br>
        <br><br>
        <input type="button" value="OK"
             onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success_callback).getCredentials(this.parentNode)" />    
        <input type="button" value="Close"
             onclick="google.script.host.close()" />

    </form>

    <script>

       // Using this call back prevents the need to hit the Close Button after OK.
       function success_callback() {
         google.script.host.close(); // Close the dialog.
       }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need a response from the server-side function, simply omit 'withSuccessHandler';

```
function func_client(){

google.script.run.func_server();
google.script.host.close();


}
```

In this case, the server-side code will continue executing without locking your client's UI - you can call any other functions inside 'func_server'.

If you'd like to process a response from the first function call, call the second function from 'success_callback'. The dialog will be closed without waiting for the google.script.run to complete, but the server code will continue executing. 
In the example below, the 1st server function passes form data back to the client where 'success_callback' immediately invokes another server function that takes a while to complete (it logs each file in my Google Drive);

Client:

```
 <form id="form">
    .....
        <input type="submit" id="ok" value="OK" />    
        <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />    
    .....
   </form>

<script>
   window.onload = function(){

    document.getElementById("form")
            .addEventListener("submit", function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    google.script.run
                 .withSuccessHandler(success_callback)
                 .logFormData(this);

});


}

   function success_callback(response) {

     console.log(response);

     google.script.run.scanFiles();
     google.script.host.close(); // Close the dialog.
   }
</script>
```

Server:

```
function showDialog(){

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

//IMPORTANT: client-side scripts won't be executed 
//without calling evaluate() on the HtmlTemplate object before passing it to UI;

var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("dialog");
var html = template.evaluate();

ui.showModalDialog(html, "dialog");


}


function logFormData(formData){


return formData;

}


function scanFiles() {

var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
var file;  

  while (files.hasNext()) {

  file = files.next();

    Logger.log(file.getName() + ": " + file.getMimeType());


  }


}
```

Comment: Anton, thanks. You helped me determine what was going on.

A word of caution for anyone else: Logger.Log() isn't much use when trying to trace the execution of this kind of code, as each server-side function called from the client-side dialog seems to reset the Log overwriting what was already there. So Logger doesn't tell you which server-side functions have actually run; just the last one. Trace function calls by writing to spreadsheet cells instead.

And because of the above, I'd missed that the showModelDialog() call doesn't actually block, which was the source of my confusion.